# Combining multiple queries

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 queries given below. Now I want to have one quey by combining the two queries so as to get the table with columns (`Tag Number`, `Primary Name` and `Discoverd Name`)

Query 1:

```
select  RT.[TagName] as 'Tag Number',
        RA.SourceName as 'Primary Document',
        RA.SourceRevision
from dbo.REP_TTA as RT 
join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
where RA.[AssocName]='is a document for'
```

Query 2:

```
select RT.[TagName] as 'Tag Number',
       RA.SourceName as 'Discoverd Document',
      RA.SourceRevision 
from dbo.REP_TransposedTagAttributes as RT 
join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
where RA.[AssociationName]='refers to'
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `dbo.REP_TTA` is NOT the same table as `dbo.REP_TransposedTagAttributes`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can guess, you have 'Primary Document' and 'Discovered Document' in different rows of REP_ASS, which means you'll need to join REP_ASS twice anyway... So here it goes:

```
select RPrimary.[TagName] as 'Tag Number',
       RPrimary.sourceName as 'Primary Document',
       RDiscovered.SourceName as 'Discoverd Document',
       RPrimary.SourceRevision
from
    (select  RT.[TagName],
            RA.SourceName,
            RA.SourceRevision
    from dbo.REP_TTA as RT 
    join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
    where RA.[AssocName]='is a document for'
    ) AS RPrimary
inner join --or outer if you don't have them all in both tables yet want them all
    (select RT.[TagName],
           RA.SourceName
    from dbo.REP_TransposedTagAttributes as RT 
    join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
    where RA.[AssociationName]='refers to'
    ) AS RDiscovered
on RPrimary.[TagName] = RDiscovered.[TagName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) (if you want to remove duplicates) or UNION ALL (to keep the duplicates)

Note that number of columns and their types have to match.

```
select  RT.[TagName] as 'Tag Number',
    RA.SourceName as 'Primary Document',
    RA.SourceRevision
from dbo.REP_TTA as RT 
join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
where RA.[AssocName]='is a document for'

UNION ALL -- or just UNION

select RT.[TagName] as 'Tag Number',
   RA.SourceName as 'Discoverd Document',
   RA.SourceRevision 
from dbo.REP_TransposedTagAttributes as RT 
join dbo.REP_ASS as RA on RA.TargetName=RT.TagName
where RA.[AssociationName]='refers to'
```